# Wordpress archive pages url change

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, archive

I have my blog archive to show the months and i can access them by going at

```
http://www.mysite.com/date/2014/02
```

Now, i want to change these links to something like

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog/date/2014/02
```

without changing the permalinks admin panel setting.

Is it possible to achieve this by coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea of what you want can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes) and [here](http://ruslanbes.com/devblog/2013/04/03/wordpress-routing-explained/).

Install [WP Router](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-router/), and what you will have at end will be something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_router_generate_routes', 'bl_add_routes', 20 );

function bl_add_routes( $router ) { 
$route_args = array(
                    'path' => '^blog',
                    'query_vars' => array( ),
                    'page_callback' => 'bl_new_demo_route_callback',
                    'page_arguments' => array( ),
                    'access_callback' => true,
                    'title' => __( 'Blog/Date' ),
                    'template' => array(
                                'page.php',
                            dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/page.php'
                    )
            );

$router->add_route( 'demo-route-id', $route_args );
}

function bl_new_demo_route_callback( ) {
    return "Congrats!";
}
```

[Here](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/35542/wordpress-creating-new-routes-custom-urls-with-wp-router) is another reading which is more straight forward.